# Is it possible to get explain plan with bind variables in DB2?

Tags: db2, sql-execution-plan

With Oracle, the syntax is:

```
explain plan for
select * from users WHERE user_name = :user_name AND user_dob = :user_dob
```

Is it possible to do the same in DB2? The statement below does not seem to work.

```
explain plan with snapshot for
select * from users WHERE user_name = :user_name AND user_dob = :user_dob
```

Thank you.

Comment: What OS is your DB2 server running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer may depend on your DB2 version and platform, which you chose not to share with us for some reason. This works fine on DB2 for LUW (v10.1, but I'm sure it would work with v9.7 and up):

```
$ db2 "explain plan with snapshot for select * from syscat.schemata where schemaname = :blah"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

You may want to try replacing named parameter markers with questions marks.

Comment: Changing the statement to "select * from users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_dob = ?" worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is in the IBM website, but it is not easy to make sense of.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000952.htm

> FOR explainable-sql-statement
>
> Specifies the SQL statement to be explained. This statement can be any
>   valid CALL, Compound SQL (Dynamic), DELETE, INSERT, MERGE, SELECT,
>   SELECT INTO, UPDATE, VALUES, or VALUES INTO SQL statement. If the
>   EXPLAIN statement is embedded in a program, the
>   explainable-sql-statement can contain references to host variables
>   (these variables must be defined in the program).  Similarly, if
>   EXPLAIN is being dynamically prepared, the explainable-sql-statement
>   can contain **parameter markers**.

But it does not tell you what "parameter markers" are, so you have to go and search for it.